# Can't install any package via command line tool with -Version switch

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-2013, nuget, command-line-tool

Does anyone else experience this? I reported this issue like over 2 months ago. Not 1 reply on codeplex.

I'm using visual studio 2013 ultimate with update 1. Package Manager Console Host Version 2.8.50313.46.

This is the message I get if I try to install (for example) T4MVC:

`PM> Install-Package T4MVC -Version 3.8.0
Install-Package : Unable to find version '3.8.0' of package 'T4MVC'.
At line:1 char:16
+ Install-Package <<<<  T4MVC -Version 3.8.0
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand`

If I don't use the -Version switch, it works fine.

For now, I'm looking for a work-around. Can't effort to wait another 2 months or something.

If anyone could help me with this issue, please do so! I'd really really really appreciate it!

Comment: What package sources are defined?

Comment: No idea what it means, how can I find out?

Comment: See *Package Sources* section here http://docs.nuget.org/docs/start-here/managing-nuget-packages-using-the-dialog

Comment: It's set on https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/ . Is that the default?

Comment: Yes. I was thinking you may have added a package source that didn't include that package. I'm not at my computer to see if I can repro this. I'll comment if I think of anything else.

Comment: There is only one package source that I pasted in my previous post if that's what you mean.

Comment: It works for me on VS 2013 Ultimate w/Update 1 with NuGet 2.8.50313.46. `Successfully added 'T4MVC 3.8.0' to WebApplication1.`.

Comment: I have the update 1 too. Updating the question.

Comment: Change the package source url to http://www.nuget.org/api/v2/ and install Fiddler and see what requests are being made to nuget.org. Changing the url to http instead of https will allow you to see the requests.

Comment: Just tried your suggestion, I don't see anything in the Fiddler passing by concerning nuget.org. Created a new source, removed the 's' in https, and moved it to the top. I don't have any filters turned on either in Fiddler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `Package Manager Console` (`PMC`) there is a drop down menu at the top-left side with the label "Package source:". The selected text was "Microsoft and .NET", while it should have been "nuget.org". Changing it from "Microsoft and .NET" to "nuget.org" fixed the problem.

This really really really sucked!

Comment: Hey, glad you figured it out. So it was related to Package Source after all. The default Package Source should be "All" (which means it goes through each available package source in order).

Comment: Yea, I have no idea how the selected value changed. Never touched it as far as I know. Thanks for the tip, just changed it again. Make from your comment an answer and I'll mark it.